# how to create a ".avsc" file from an input avro file?

Tags: shell, unix, avro

how to create a ".avsc" file from avro header ?

Does the first line of content is a avsc file for that avro? 
Or does the avsc content should starts from : {"type":"record" upto "}avro?

I tried the above mentioned 2 steps but not able to generate expected avsc file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are different ways to do this. You can to use using avro-tools  like this

```
avro-tools -getschema youravrofile
```

Or programatically like this

```
DatumReader<GenericRecord> datumReader = new GenericDatumReader<>();
DataFileReader<GenericRecord> dataFileReader = new DataFileReader<>(new File("yourfile.avro"), datumReader);
Schema schema = dataFileReader.getSchema();
System.out.println(schema); // this will print the schema for you
```